# Optimum movie schedule considering duration and no overlap

Tags: algorithm

I am struggling to find a good strategy to tackle this problem. I considered sorting the collection of movies, by duration, but that seems to obscure the overlap condition. Any ideas?

Another thing I was thinking about was sorting based on start month and then, approaching as an extension of [this problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-jumps-to-reach-end-of-a-given-array/).

> An actor is offered a set of movies for a certain (start month and
>   duration). You have to select the movies the actor should do so that
>   the actor can do the most number of movies in the year, without any
>   overlaps.
>
> It is assumed that movies start on the first of a month, and end on
>   the last day. Months are of 30 days (should not be required?).

Comment: Think in terms of sub-problems: I suggest "What are the most movies he could have participated in, ending at a certain month."

Comment: @EdwardPeters I think I see what you are getting at. But, how would the duration fit in this approach?

Comment: Here, I'll post a full answer.

Comment: This is the interval scheduling problem. A greedy approach is optimal - just try to sort by finish time (computed by start date + duration). Pick the ones which finish quickest and which don't overlap with those already picked.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Thanks, buddy!

Comment: @Liongold Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up some code to demonstrate a solution.  The overall essence is similar to what [Edward Peters mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293291/optimum-movie-schedule-considering-duration-and-no-overlap/36294032#36294032). First thing is to sort the movies by their end times. Now, greedily the first option is always chosen.

**Why does choosing the first option work?**

In our case, our ordering `A` had the first movie, some `a`. Say there is another ordering `B` where the first movie is some `b`, such that `b` ≠ `a`. There must be an ordering (we already know about the existence of `A`) such that, **`A` = {`B` – {`b`}} U {`a`}**. Obviously, in the case of `B`, `b` would have the smallest time; since **`b` ≠ `a`**, **duration(`b`) >= duration(`a`)**.

```
public class Optimum_Movie_Schedule {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Movie[] movies = new Movie[] {
            new Movie("f", 5, 9),
            new Movie("a", 1, 2),
            new Movie("b", 3, 4),
            new Movie("c", 0, 6),
            new Movie("d", 5, 7),
            new Movie("e", 8, 9)
        };

        // sort by endMonth; startMonth if endMonth clash
        Arrays.sort(movies);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(movies));

        System.out.println("Final list: ");
        System.out.print(movies[0] + " ");

        int cur = 0;
        for(int i = 1 ; i < movies.length ; i++) {
            if(movies[i].startMonth > movies[cur].endMonth) {
                System.out.print(movies[i] + " ");
                cur = i;
            }
        }
    }

    static class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {
        String name;
        int startMonth;
        int endMonth;
        int duration;
        public Movie(String name, int start, int end) {
            this.name = name;
            this.startMonth = start;
            this.endMonth = end;
            this.duration = (end + 1) - start;
        }

        public int compareTo(Movie o) {
            if(this.endMonth < o.endMonth)
                return -1;

            if(this.endMonth == o.endMonth)
                if(this.startMonth < o.startMonth)
                    return -1;

            return 1;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name + "("+ startMonth + ", " + endMonth + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take your list of movies, sorted by their end dates. For each movie, you want to solve "What are the maximum number of movies I could have acted in, by the end of this movie." This can be found recursively as the maximum of either the result for the most recent movie, or one plus the result for the most recent movie to end before this one began.

The first case corresponds to "I did not act in this movie, so would have been able to pursue other movies during that duration." The second case corresponds to "I acted in this movie, but was not available for any movies that did not end before this movie began."

Comment: I think I see how this would work. Thanks for your response! +1

Comment: Just added some code taking cues from your idea. Apologies for not getting back to this question sooner.